# VestaCP DNS record, Go daddy says "Invalid Name Servers"

Tags: dns, vps, nameservers, vesta

Okay let me explain the problem in details.  I have followed this tutorial to install VestaCP

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-vestacp-and-set-up-a-website-on-ubuntu-14-04

**Everything works fine. According to the tutorial I've created**

1. An A record pointing xeonbd.com to my Droplet's IP 67.227.216.187
2. An A record pointing ns1.xeonbd.com to my Droplet's IP 67.227.216.187
3. An A record pointing ns2.xeonbd.com to my Droplet's IP 67.227.216.187
4. An A record pointing panel.xeonbd.com to my Droplet's IP 67.227.216.187
5. A CNAME record pointing www.example.com to example.com 67.227.216.187

Everything is working fine. Now using VestaCP I've hosted another site. It is "wptips.tech" which is registered on Godaddy.

So according to the above tutorial in my domain registrar's control panel I've to update NS records and those NS records should be  ns1.xeonbd.com and ns2.xeonbd.com

### **But the problem is on Godaddy's control panel whenever I try to add those NS records it gives me a dreaded error message saying "You must enter a registered name server" :( **

Here is a screenshot of the message : https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xnn48gcgv3oh8z/1.png?dl=0

I have done google search for many hours and found solution for another problem but not as like as mine. So, please do not tell me the solution like the following

1. login to your Godaddy account.
2. navigate to domains/yourdomain
3. find "Host Names" and click on "Manage"
4. add your host name (ns1,ns2) and IP address
5. save

cause it won't work for me if I follow the above steps then it will give me option to add name servers ns1.wptips.tech and ns2.wptips.tech but according to my Vesta configuration the name servers are ns1.xeonbd.com and ns2.xeonbd.com and the domain xeonbd.com is not registered with Godaddy but 1and1 and wptips.tech is registered with Godaddy. I think you have understand the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Wher have you created all those records pointing to 67.227.216.187 ?

Comment: In my DigitalOcean droplet's DNS control panel

Answer (score 0):

You need to change DNS Template to child-ns in DNS -> Edit .